# Can't fold comments in Eclipse 3.5.2

Tags: java, eclipse

Aren't i supposed to be able to do this? Folding is enabled in the Java preferences, but no +/- button appears next to comments. I can fold imports and classes and methods, but not comments. Also, checking the Comments box in "Initially fold these elements" does nothing.

Comment: did you click on fold header comments too?

Comment: that one is checked by default.

Comment: Are you trying to fold `// ...` comments or `/* ... */`? The latter works just fine for me.

Comment: what form are your comments in? are they like this `/* ... */`?

Comment: Vote for it: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=63808

Answer (score 1):

It could be a side-effect of another option setting the code folding for a plugin you don't have.

See [bug 153449](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=153449) for an example (written at the time when Mylyn was called Mylar):

> I can enable and disable folding, and I see my editor margin increase/decrease
>   in size providing a gutter for the code folding markers to appear in, but they
>   simply aren't there.  Also, all of the menu options to expand all and collapse
>   all are there and enabled but they do nothing.
>
> Actually, I just saw this in my exported preferences:

```
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/editor_folding_provider=org.eclipse.mylar.java.ui.editor.foldingprovider
```

> And I don't have Mylar installed.  I'm betting this is the problem.  I'll try
>   to get rid of it and see what happens.